# How to perform blowfish decryption using pycrypto

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto

Hello I'm trying to perform *BlowFish Encryption/Decryption* using *pycrypto*

Here is my sample code file, The encryption works well while decrypting the data

It just prints:

```
 Hello 8g
```

instead of [this](https://8gwifi.org)

Here is the complete sample code for *BlowFIsh Encryption* and *Decryption*, not sure what padding I need to add extra, I'm aware of the fact that BlowFISH  has a fixed data block size of 8 bytes and its keys can vary in length from *32 to 448 bits* (4 to 56 bytes).

```
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
from Crypto import Random
from struct import pack
bs = Blowfish.block_size
import os


encryptedpass = "myverystrongpassword"
plaintextMessage = "Hello 8gwifi.org"

iv = os.urandom(Blowfish.block_size)
bs = Blowfish.block_size


# ENcryption
cipher = Blowfish.new(encryptedpass, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, iv)
plen = bs - divmod(len(plaintextMessage),bs)[1]
padding = [plen]*plen
padding = pack('b'*plen, *padding)
ct = iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintextMessage + padding)


#Decryption
cipher = Blowfish.new(encryptedpass, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, iv)
msg = cipher.decrypt(ct[bs:])

print msg
```

Answer (score 0):

You failed to remove the padding after decrypt. Your padding is 8 bytes of the ASCII character "\x08", also known as the backspace character. When you printed it your terminal dutifully "backspaced" over and erased the previous 8 characters which were "wifi.org".

Comment: Help me to fix the code, I did encrypt with padding, and doing decryption with padding